# Implementar navegação com botões: [primeiro] [próximo] [anterior] [último]

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, paginação

## Explicação:

Possuo uma tabela em HTML+jQuery e tenho uma paginação enumerada que está funcional, porém gostaria de adicionar uma navegação adicional à ela.

## Pergunta:

Gostaria de adicionar uma implementação, da qual, seria uma navegação com 4 botões que deve funcionar da seguinte forma:

1. Botão: <kbd>Primeiro</kbd> - funcionalidade: navegar até a primeira página.
2. Botão: <kbd>Anterior</kbd> - funcionalidade: navegar até a página anterior.
3. Botão: <kbd>Próximo</kbd>  - funcionalidade: navegar até a próxima página.
4. Botão: <kbd>Último</kbd>   - funcionalidade: navegar até a ultima página.

## Observação:

Eu utilizo o paginate do jQuery em minha tabela, conforme o exemplo demonstra.

## Exemplo:

#### **[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dp29fvmn/)**

**SOLUÇÃO**

encontrei esse plugin do jquery na net, solucionou meu caso, obrigado jQuery*-*

http://datatables.net/

Comment: Eu usei esse plugin uma vez http://esimakin.github.io/twbs-pagination/ veja se é isso que precisa.

Comment: [Posso mostrar só um link pro meu site/jsfiddle com problemas?](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/1913/201)

Comment: sim @brasofilo pode sim

Comment: ?? pode então por favor publicar uma resposta lá no Meta que defenda o SIM?

Comment: nao entendi o que vc quis dizer ??

Comment: Tomei a liberdade de editar a pergunta para que fique de forma bem legível, explicada e fácil de entender, porém tomei o cuidado de manter o sentido e o contexto original da pergunta.

Comment: @Furlan, perdão, achei que só colocando o link para o FAQ explicava o assunto... Dá um confere lá na discussão para ver qual o problema.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode adicionar da mesma forma que criou as páginas, segue implementação dos botões que você pediu, que funcionam exatamente da mesma forma que a paginação:

## Botão Anterior(prev)

```
$('<span class="page-number"></span>').text('Ant.').bind('click', { 
        newPage: currentPage-1
}, function(event) { 
    if (currentPage > 0){
      currentPage = currentPage-1;//event.data['newPage'];
      $table.trigger('repaginate');
      var pgSelected = $('.active').prev();
      $(this).siblings().removeClass('active');    
      pgSelected.addClass('active');
    }
}).prependTo($pager).addClass('clickable');
```

## Botão Próximo(next)

```
$('<span class="page-number"></span>').text('Prox.').bind('click', { 
    newPage: currentPage+1
}, function(event) { 
if (currentPage < numPages-1){
    currentPage = currentPage+1;//event.data['newPage'];
    $table.trigger('repaginate');
    var pgSelected = $('.active').next();
    $(this).siblings().removeClass('active');    
    pgSelected.addClass('active');
  }
}).appendTo($pager).addClass('clickable');
```

## Botão Primeiro(first)

```
$('<span class="page-number"></span>').text('First').bind('click', { 
        newPage: 1
    }, function(event) { 
        currentPage = 1;//event.data['newPage'];
        $table.trigger('repaginate');
        var pgSelected = $('.page-number').eq(2);
        $(this).siblings().removeClass('active');    
        pgSelected.addClass('active');
    }).prependTo($pager).addClass('clickable');
```

## Botão Último(last)

```
$('<span class="page-number"></span>').text('Ult.').bind('click', { 
        newPage: numPages-1
    }, function(event) { 
        currentPage = numPages-1;//event.data['newPage'];
        $table.trigger('repaginate');
        var pgLen = $('.page-number').length;
        var pgSelected = $('.page-number').eq(pgLen-3);
        $(this).siblings().removeClass('active');    
        pgSelected.addClass('active');
    }).appendTo($pager).addClass('clickable')
```

Basta adicionar estes códigos ao javascript e eles estarão funcionando, segue exemplo funcionando no <kbd>[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dp29fvmn/2/)</kbd>.

## Observações:

A implementação dos botões segue mesma lógica da implementação das páginas porém a mudança está no controle da pagina atual (currentPage) e de pagina a ser selecionada pela tabela, por isso no caso do próximo e anterior é simplesmente `currentPage-1` e `currentPage+1` com ajuda das funções `prev()` e `next()` do jquery que identificam o elemento anterior(prev) e o elemento proximo(next) respectivamente, foi possível adicionar a classe `active` para o elemento assim realizando a transição visual e setando o `currentPage` como eu disse anteriormente, é possível fazer esta transição na própria table. Para o primeiro seria apenas selecionar a primeira página, que seria o elemento `2` por causa dos botões primeiro e anterior que são `0` e `1`. Já o último, você apenas deve pegar o tamanho da sua paginação e diminuir 1 que seria setar o `currentPage` para `numPages-1`, porém a parte visual para adicionar o `active` neste caso seria o elemento `numPages-3` pelo fato que existem dois botões no fim que seriam o próximo e o último.

Comment: muito obrigado @Paulo, salvou o dia

Comment: tem como esconder as proximas paginações, por exemplo, a paginação vai de 1 ate 100, ficar assim: 1 2 3 4 5 ...,

Comment: qual o comando para nao mostrar todas as paginações, por que ta saindo do espaço, teria que tipo encurtar, mostrar 5 paginate por ex., [1][2][3][4][5]...[10][11]

Comment: poderia aguardar? em breve atualizarei minha resposta, estou meio ocupado hoje @Furlan

Comment: aguardo sim @Paulo , obrigado pela atenção,